# Exception when parse decimal

Tags: c#, parsing, decimal

I have the following number in a textbox and when I parse it I get an Exception:
560.00

My parse code:

```
unitPrice = decimal.Parse(this.txtUnitPrice.Text);
```

Any idea why i am getting an Exception?

Comment: What is your ``CultureInfo.CurrentCulture``?

Comment: "560.00" - That doesn't look like an exception. Try posting the actual exception text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var unitPrice = decimal.Parse(txtUnitPrice.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

      Console.WriteLine(unitPrice.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

[Convert.ToDecimal Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa325121%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The `decimal.Parse` method comes with 3 overloads that accept `NumberStyles` & `IFormatProvider`. You can use the `NumberStyles` parameter to make sure your parsing will work OK on any machine, regardless if there is '.', or ',' used as a decimal point.